# How to convert Avro to JSON in java

Tags: java, avro

I'm using below code. However it gives this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Malformed data. Length is negative: -40
```

The code is below, However, if you have any other code which works I'm ok with replacing it. This function is going to be called from groovy script in boomi:

```
public static String getavroToJson(Schema schema, byte[] avroBinary) throws IOException {
    // byte to datum
    DatumReader<Object> datumReader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
    Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(avroBinary, null);
    Object avroDatum = datumReader.read(null, decoder);

    // datum to json
    String json = null;
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
      DatumWriter<Object> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
      JsonEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(schema, baos, false);
      writer.write(avroDatum, encoder);
      //encoder.flush();
     //baos.flush();
      
      json = new String(baos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      
    }
```

Comment: Where exactly does `avroBinary` come from? Assuming it is from Kafka, and if the Avro data is assocatied with Confluent Schema Registry, then that would explain this error (the byte array is not the correct length to decode)

Comment: We are converting inputstream to ByteArray format and storing it in avroBinary. We have checked and the array contains data.

Comment: Sure, it may contain anything, but the `binaryEncoder` expects a particular length, as the error says... Where does the InputStream come from?

Comment: Ultimately, you're just rewriting the `convertToJson` method of this project anyway https://github.com/allegro/json-avro-converter

Comment: The InputStream is coming from Kafka Azure Event Hub in Avro format

Comment: Okay. Getting closer. This "Avro format" comes from the Confluent Schema Registry serializer? If so, the `binaryDecoder` is not able to process it... In other words, what exactly does your Kafka producer code look like?